# Change the behavior of super key alone

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I want to know whether there is a way to use super(win) key alone as shortcut without change its function as a modifier.

On ubuntu, by default, pressing and then releasing super key, without pressing other keys, will invoke activity overview. But I want it to invoke a shell script written by me. And when super key and other key are pressed simultaneously, I want it to function as before.

I know how to disable super key from invoking activity overview in `dconf-editor`, but I do not know how to remap it.

Comment: did you try `xcape` ?? `sudo apt install xcape`

Comment: @UnKNOWn xcape works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed put pressing and releasing <kbd>Super</kbd> to your own use with a utility like `xcape` (present in the default Ubuntu repositories) or `ksuperkey`.

You first need to disable the default assignment of <kbd>Super</kbd> in Gnome Shell:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
```

Then you can use `xcape` to redirect pressing and releasing <kbd>Super</kbd> alone to a regular shortcut key combination, in particular the regular keyboard combination you use to launch your script.

For example, suppose we want <kbd>Super</kbd> to display the application overview. That action is already bound to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, so to achieve that, we autostart the following command on login:

```
xcape -e "Super_L=Super_L|a"  #Load
```

For your custom script, assign it a regular shortcut first using "Settings - Keyboard Shortcuts" and substitute `Super_L|a` by that shortcut key.

To undo, disable the autostart command and reset the dconf key to default with the command `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfect! And I never thought I could receive a reply in such a short time! But just one more thing to mention, the setting of super key for activity overview is not set at `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu`, but `org.gnome.mutter.overlay-key`, at least on my machine.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't comment the accepted answer. But in Ubuntu 22.04 to **remove** the default behavior I needed to do: `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''`

Comment: @andir Thank you very much, this was wrong in the answer, as Simon already commented long time ago, but I must have missed that. I now corrected the answer. I wrongly put `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu`, but this is set to open the overview with Alt+F1, not Super